# Where do I find Pikachu in Pokemon Ultra Moon?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

I'd like to find Pikachu in Pokemon Ultra Moon, how do I find it? Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Where have you looked? Surely sites like Bulbapedia or Serebii would have this info readily available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pikachu is not a reliable encounter - Pichu on Route 1 can SOS for a Pikachu but you'll only have a 5% chance of that happening. Your most reliable way to just to capture of Pichu and evolve it.

In Ultra Sun & Moon Pichu spawn in only one place - Route 1. They spawn in the grass patches to the top-right of Route 1, where the cliff edge overlooks the ocean.

With a rarity rating of 5%, this Pokemon is extremely difficult to find. They'll be level 2 or 3, and can spawn day or night.
If the Pichu calls an SOS, there's also a 5% ratiy Pikachu that can come to its aid.

In order to evolve your Pichu, maximize its [friendship](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#In_Generation_VII) (Credit: Nolonar). Once fully affectionate to you, Pichu will evolve on the next level up.

**[SOURCE](https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/6358-pokemon-ultra-sun-moon-guide-locations-for-pichu-ditto-rockruff-noibat-inkay-and-other-useful-pokemon)**

Comment: While Pichu does evolve to Pikachu, why does your answer detail finding a Pichu when the OP asked about Pikachu?

Comment: @Wondercricket Great point, I missed the part in explaining why Pichu is more reliable way of getting Pikachu. Will update my answer. Thank you

Comment: Pokémon Refresh is used to evolve Eevee into Sylveon. Pichu evolves through [Friendship](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#In_Generation_VII), which has nothing to do with Refresh. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @Nolonar Thanks for that, I'll update my answer with this info

Answer (score 1):

By looking up pikachu for [*Ultra Moon*](https://www.rpgsite.net/feature/6364-pokemon-ultra-sun-moon-pikachu-valley-guide-how-to-reach-the-valley-and-get-the-i-choose-you-cap-pikachu), you can learn that there is a *Pikachu Valley* where you can get the exclusive cap pikachu. It is located on route 4 on Akala island.

Comment: This pikachu is unable to evolve, though.